# What dependency injection pattern to use for a MessageProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, service-locator, ambientcontext

I have a ContactController where I set up a message in the `TempData` (this is to display a message in the screen after successful submission) and in the layout, there's a partial `_Message.cshtml` that is supposed to render the message, if any. Method signatures below:

```
List<Message> GetMessages(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary);
void SetMessage(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, string body, MessageType type);
```

Initially I thought about having a `MessageProvider` dependency injected in the constructor. But then it occurred to me: What if I need do this in other controllers? Besides, for me to use it in the partial view, I need to resolve the implementation from the container which I think is an acceptable solution to use in a class that extends `WebViewPage` (considering I am not going to unit test it).

```
public MyCustomViewPage()
{
  this.MessageProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MessageProvider>();
}

public MessageProvider MessageProvider { get; set; }
```

But can we avoid the `Service Locator` anti-pattern using another dependency injection pattern?

I was thinking this `MessageProvider` has a good default implementation and since we might need to use this in more controllers in the future, this might be a good candidate for `Ambient Context` design pattern as per the book [Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/).

This way, I would eliminate the potential problem of having to change other controller constructors in the future in case I happen to have to set messages in them, I would eliminate the need to use the `Service Locator` anti-pattern in the `MyCustomViewPage` constructor and my controller will still be testable.

I would then use the following code in partial view:

```
var messages = MessageProvider.Current.GetMessages()
```

And the following code in my controllers:

```
MessageProvider.Current.SetMessage("Message sent successfully.", MessageType.Success);
```

And in my test fixtures (if I would actually need another implementation):

```
MessageProvider.SetMessageProvider(otherImplementation);
```

Do you think this approach makes sense? Any downsides I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might be looking for the same answer in the future, I decided to use `Ambient Context` for this because of the reasons I mentioned in the quesiton.